# Label not getting value

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to assign a value to Label, but at start the count is always 0.
How can I get and assign values to label?

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (viewModelg.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            viewModelg.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
            Items = new List<Holtak>();
            Items = viewModelg.Items.ToList();

            Task.WaitAll();

            totalText.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(33, 150, 243);
            totalText.TextColor = Color.FromRgb(255,255,255);
            totalText.Text = "Halottak száma: " + Items.Count;
        }

        SfDataGrid dataGrid = new SfDataGrid();
        dataGrid.GridStyle = new Dark();
    }
```

Comment: Could you check if `Items` contain value after call `viewModelg.Items.ToList()`?

Comment: Do you have any updates for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You are running the code block where you set the labelText only if the count is 0 so of course you'll always see 0 as the count. You should place the line `totalText.Text = "Halottak száma: " + Items.Count;` after the if block, also make sure that `Items.Count` is not 0.

Comment: I moved "Task.WaitAll();..." to "...+ Items.Count;" outside the if, but the value of Items.Count is still 0

Comment: That is because it is 0. the count of your viewModelg.Items is 0, you just pass that as a list, and get that list's count it will still be 0. Try adding items to your viewModelg.Items.